# C++ ifstream will not open any files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

Whenever I try to open a file with ifstream, it compiles fine, but will not open the file.
The file in this example doesn't exist, but ifstream *s*should*s* create the file for me.

i have some example code that i think should work, but does not open or create the file
"foo.txt". Is there something that i'm missing, or is my IDE just messed up?
i'm using visual studio 2008 VC++ , btw

thanks

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream in;
    string hold;
    in.open("foo.txt",ios::in);
    if(!in){
        cerr << "Couldn't open file!" << endl;
    }
    in >> hold;
    cout << hold << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should? Hrm. Even if it created your input file, what would you expect to extract from the file?

Comment: Did you check to make sure the path is good?  Try using the full path?  Also, while it probably doesn't matter, try using `if (!in.good())`

Comment: An *input* stream will not create a file.

Comment: As mentioned an ifstream is an input stream so it will not create a file if it does not exist.  I always think of the >> or << as indicating where the data is going 
i.e. 
`cerr << "some text"; //"some text is going to the stderr stream`
`in >> hold; //data from the in stream is going to the hold variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using an in stream instead of an out stream, as Adam Liss mentioned(`ios::out` rather than `ios::in`). You also need to make sure you close the file before `return 0;` to make sure everything from the buffer is actually written to the file.

Comment: Wouldn't that only matter if it was an `ofstream`?

Comment: @Lander You might actually be correct. I tend to get my ifstream and ofstream mixed up

Answer (score 1):

The `open` function will not create files in `ios::in` mode; you need to use `ios::out`.